# Sending Printer Commands via USB in C#

Tags: c#, usb, printing

I have a ticket printer I am trying to send raw print commands to,

I am currently sending the commands by pinvoke to winspool.drv and calling WritePrinter. This is working for most of the commands I am sending, but I cannot get feedback from the printer this way (for example, the printer has a barcode reader on it, I can send them command read barcode but I cannot receive the data back as it is stopped by the windows spooler).

Is there a way to open a USB port and send a byte[] of commands in C#?

Many Thanks

Shaun

Comment: The API for it is call Bidi Communications.  Very rough from C#, this is a COM interface without a type library.  Talk to the printer manufacturer, this must be a common need for that printer model.  That bar code reader is useless without it.  Next time you ask a question like this, be sure to document details.  Like the printer model number.

Answer (score 1):

You can exchange data over USB in a similar manner as you read/write to a file. Here's an interesting [article on that topic](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84338/making-usb-c-friendly/).

Using the windows printer driver has some advantages though. Are you sure you want to do this yourself?